# Working with require_once

Tags: php, constants

I am working with the function require_once but keep getting errors when trying  to run the page. Tried looking elsewhere but can't seem to get a precise answer for my problem. My code is:

```
    <?php
        require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'Pages/Page.php'); 
        require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'lib/Application/Authentication/namespace.php');
```

It gives me the following errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_DIR - assumed 'ROOT_DIR' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myDiary/Pages/LoginPage.php on line 3
>
> Warning: require_once(ROOT_DIRPages/Page.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myDiary/Pages/LoginPage.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ROOT_DIRPages/Page.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myDiary/Pages/LoginPage.php on line 3.

Please explain what my problem is, I haven't been programming for very long.

Comment: Have you defined the constant ROOT_DIR? Also, this has nothing to do with either apache or mysql.

Comment: is there any problem..? have you got the solution

Comment: I defining the ROOT_DIR solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the constant `ROOT_DIR` on top:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', '/path/to/your/scripts/');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all clearly stated in the error messages:

- Your constant `ROOT_DIR` is not defined at that position in the script,
- so PHP can't find the respective files,
- which results in the `require_once()` call failing.

As a solution make sure to set `ROOT_DIR` before using it. See [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) for this.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that first

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error since you haven't defined the directory

define this by

```
define('ROOT_DIR', '/path/to/your/scripts/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define ROOT_DIR first.. like so:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', 'path');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DOCUMENT_ROOT

```
<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= 'Pages/Page.php';
  include_once($path);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work

```
require_once(__ROOT__.'Pages/Page.php');
```

the useful link is here  :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: This will not work as well since __ROOT__ would also have to be defined first.